# AVAudion Session Interruption

Tags: ios

` setSession()
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        becomeFirstResponder()

```
    NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, Selector("handleInterruption"), name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: nil)
        //the Error is the line above this comment

    player = Player()

    player.playStream(fileUrl: "http:wwwwww.mp3")

        updatePlayButton()`
```

Im trying to check when a phone call has finished by using AVAudiointerruptionNotification but I'm doing something wrong I keep getting the Argument labels _, _, name, object do not match any available overloads...

Comment: Im trying to check when a phone call has finished by using AVAudiointerruptionNotification but I'm doing something wrong I keep getting the Argument labels  _, _, name, object do not match any available overloads...

Answer (score 0):

The new way of using the Notification center in swift 3 is as fallows. I was able to compile with no errors or warnings!

```
   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
   (Selector("handleInterruption")), name:
   NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
```